# Plugin nativescript-mapbox is not included in preview app on device

Tags: mapbox, nativescript-angular

Plugin nativescript-mapbox is not included in preview app on device

tns plugin add nativescript-mapbox

anyone experiencing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means exactly what it says. The Nativescript Preview app only has a limited number of libraries installed, making it usable only for basic, simple apps.

> The Preview app comes with a predefined set of NativeScript plugins. If your app > utilizes a plugin that is not present in the Preview app, you will see a warning > message and your app might not work as expected.
>
> [tns preview documentation](https://docs.nativescript.org/tooling/docs-cli/project/testing/preview)

The best solution while developing your app is to use emulators.

As a side note, from my experience, I've found that the iOS Preview app has more plugins and generally works better.